# For load balancing which is preferable Node Clusters or using axios / http-proxy-middleware and Node container is dockerized

Tags: node.js, docker, load-balancing, http-proxy-middleware

[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfvXa.png)
axios for load balancing

I am trying out the concepts of load balancing and I am not sure which method is suitable and works well when I dockerize the Node application

I haven't tried any implementation and i'm having doubt which one to use and I am short on time

Answer (score 0):

NGINX is the load balancer. It will be the front facing gateway to your apps. NGINX can do SSL offload as well as load balancing. It runs as a container. It's free. Relatively easy to setup.